# CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth with inner rounding?

Tags: quartz-2d, cgcontext

I'm drawing a rounded rectangle on iOS.

This rectangle has an image background which I am clipping with a bezier path and I am then drawing a stroke with a width of two pixels inside it.

My issue is that the stroke has sharp edges on the inside instead of seemingly following the rounded rect path.

Here's a screenshot where I have increased the white colour to show the issue I'm dealing with.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGPathRef strokeRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:2].CGPath;
CGContextAddPath(context, strokeRect);
CGContextClip(context);

// draw background
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] drawInRect:rect];

// draw stroke
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.1);
CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, rect, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're going to have to do is clip the context on the inside with the corner radius and fill the context with 10% white.